# onBefore event on react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-router

Can I call Meteor method before react-router redirect me to a page? 
I would like to make a history of the logged-in user about his/her page views.

I see that in iron-router I can use   `onBeforeAction: function () {}`

I cant find similar event handler for react-router of ReactTraining.
I am searching in their docs, https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/1.0.x/docs

In meteor server side, I am using simple:json-routes. I searched also their docs and can't find anything related to onBeforeAction event handler.

I am using react-router so I can't use iron-router at the same time. So Is there any way to log the page views of a logged-in user in Meteor-ReactJS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to listen to the browser history [browserHistory.listen](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/1.0.x/docs/guides/basics/Histories.md)

But first you have to detect the current location with getCurrentLocation

Comment: Can you give a simple sample?

Comment: browserHistory.listen(function(ev) {
  console.log('listen', ev.pathname);
});

<Router history={browserHistory}>{routes}</Router>

Comment: I created a config file. and I code to that file all Router component. So I will  just import browserHistory module, then I will add history={browserHistory} to all Router component?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

By :

- encapsulating the redirection logic in one method AND
- using a library for *event oriented programming like [mufa](/questions/tagged/mufa)

## router-helper.js

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router' ; 
import {fire} from 'mufa';

export function redirect(to) {
     fire('onBeforeRedirect', to);
     browserHistory.push(to);
     fire('onAfterRedirect', to);
}
```

## OtherFile-Subscribe-OnBefore.js

```
import {on} from 'mufa';

on('onBeforeRedirect', (to) => {
   //Your code here will be running before redirection .
});
```

## Component-Call-Redirect.js

```
import {redirect} from 'router-helper';


 //...

  redirect('/profile'); //<-- This call will trigger also onBefore listeners
```