# What is the alternatie of Angular JS $transitions.onBefore event in the React JS

Tags: reactjs, angular, react-hooks

I need to check the session storage for some attributes and based on it I need to redirect the user to eitther sign in page or to the corresponding component.

This is very easy to do in Angular JS using the $transitions.onBefore event. For example belo is the code:

```
$transitions.onBefore({to: 'app'}, function (trans) {
        var isReload = trans.options().reload;
        trans.abort();
        if(!$sessionStorage.token){
            $sessionStorage.$reset();
            return $state.go('login');
        }
```

How can i achieve the same in the React JS.

Like Angular, I want to implement it in a single place instead of in all component.

May be somethhing like [React Hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) can be useful to implement this but didnt get any similar workflow example.

Comment: React doesn't have routing by default. Maybe you could use a library like react-router?

Comment: React roter has something like $transition?

Comment: Maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42576444/onbefore-event-on-react-router

Comment: I'd use a `Guard`: https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate